# jquery getJSON called multiple times breaking

Tags: jquery, getjson

A single call to getJSON, works just fine...

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12" >
    <label for="pickers" >Picker</label>
    <select name="Picker" id="selectPicker" class="form-control" ></select>
    <label for="grinners" >Grinner</label>
    <select name="Grinner" id="selectGrinner" class="form-control" ></select>
</div>

<script>
$( document ).ready( function() {

    //pickers
    $.getJSON( '/people.php', { get:'pickers' }, function( p ){

        var pOptions = '';
        for ( var pi=0; pi<=k['DATA'].length; pi++ ) {

            pOptions += '<option value="' + p['DATA'][pi][0] + '">' + p['DATA'][pi][1] + ' (' + p['DATA'][pi][2] + ')</option>';

        }

        $( '#selectPicker' ).html( pOptions );
    });



});
</script>
```

however - when I add another call, It breaks both of them I get the call, and the response, just fine, the JSON object are being returned, but the UI is not populating the selects...

The above works, If I add this (below) it breaks both selects...
I've named all vars different, so I shouldn't be getting any collisions...

```
<script>
$( document ).ready( function() {

    //pickers
    $.getJSON( '/people.php', { get:'pickers' }, function( p ){

        var pOptions = '';
        for ( var pi=0; pi<=k['DATA'].length; pi++ ) {

            pOptions += '<option value="' + p['DATA'][pi][0] + '">' + p['DATA'][pi][1] + ' (' + p['DATA'][pi][2] + ')</option>';

        }

        $( '#selectPicker' ).html( pOptions );
    });

    //grinners
    $.getJSON( '/people.php', { get:'grinners' }, function( g ){

        var gOptions = '';
        for ( var gi=0; gi<=g['DATA'].length; gi++ ) {

            gOptions += '<option value="' + g['DATA'][gi][0] + '">' + g['DATA'][gi][1] + ' (' + g['DATA'][gi][2] + ')</option>';

        }

        $( '#selectGrinner' ).html( gOptions );
    });

});
</script>
```

The JSON looks like this (just FYI):

Pickers;

```
{

    "COLUMNS":["ID","PERSON","POSITION"],
    "DATA":[[1,"Jo Bob","Banjo"],[2,"Garth Waller","jug"],[3,"Boswell Higgins","washboard"]]

}
```

Grinners;

```
{

    "COLUMNS":["ID","PERSON","RELATION"],
    "DATA":[[1,"Jimmy John","Grand-pappy"],[2,"Margie Monroe","Grammy"],[3,"'big' Tom Turney","cousin/brother"]]

}
```

Comment: I am not sure but the problem must be because of URL catching

Comment: You should check what gets inserted into the dom. It could be that some of the characters inserted are not escaped and therefore break the dom structure.

Comment: you have a typo on `pickers` `for` loop `k['DATA']` should be `p['DATA']`

Comment: Would you provide some fiddle with fake data for this?
Is there any javascript error thrown in console?

Comment: Is your JSON exactly the same as above? What do you get when you use `console.log(g['DATA'].length)`?

Comment: @roullie - yes the k should be a p - it is in the code, this is not th eissue (good eye).

Comment: @red - the JSON is a longer set, I truncated it for the post, but more or less exact.

Comment: @Parag, I'll see what I can do... I'm taking a wholly different approach to get around this issue - using .ajax() and .fail() .done(), at least IM getting messages back!

Answer (score 0):

If at all problem is with URL catching my solution is to add a date request parameter to URL like,

```
 '/people.php?d="+ new Date()
```

Where new Date() is current javascript date.
Optionaly you can make is one call and manage your server code to return both responce in one.

Comment: I suspect you are correct to a degree, however, this did not fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

for this particular issue - I think the "one" issue to fix it is the "<=" in my for loop is wrong, it should only be "<". That seems to fix that problem.

```
 for ( var pi = 0; pi <= p['DATA'].length; pi++ ) {
```

Should be

```
 for ( var pi = 0; pi < p['DATA'].length; pi++ ) {
```

I need to confirm that I'm not missing my last array element, but for now it works.

However - in my path to finding a resolution, I'm coding it differently - here is a solution that is working for me, it is more verbose that I'd like (especially when learning new stuff), I coming to accept that about JS.

Oh, and it makes multiple calls without issue.

```
$( document ).ready( function() {

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/game.cfm',
            data: { get:'pickers' },
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false
        })
        .fail( function( jqXHR ) {

            $( "#msg" ).html( jqXHR.responseText + ' ' + jqXHR.statusText );

        })
        .done( function( data ) {

            if ( data['DATA'].length ) {

                var options = '';

                for ( var i = 0; i < data['DATA'].length; i++ ) {

                    options += '<option value="' + data['DATA'][i][0] + '">' + data['DATA'][i][1] + ' (' + data['DATA'][i][2] + ')</option>';

                }

                $( '#selectPicker' ).html( options );

            } else {

                $( '#selectPicker' ).html( '<option value="0" >No Selections Available</option>' );

            }

        });

        });
```